# Вопрос по методу DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern?

Tags: java

Мне необходимо преобразовать строку с датой в объект LoacalDate чтобы с ним дальше работать. Постоянно появляется сообщение: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01-Jan-2017' could not be parsed at index 3. Скопипастил текст с примера - все равно появляется тоже сообщение. Код примера ниже:

```
String date1 ="01-Jan-2017";
 DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
 d1 = LocalDate.parse(date1, df);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
String date1 ="01-янв-2017";
```